# Catch numpy ComplexWarning as Exception

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.0, 2.1j])
>>> b = np.array(a, dtype=np.float64)
/Users/goerz/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  #!/Users/goerz/anaconda3/bin/python
```

How can I catch the ComplexWarning as an Exception?

I have tried `np.seterr`, but this has no effect (as it only relates to floating point warnings such as underflows/overflows).

I've also tried the `with warnings.catch_warnings():` context manager from the standard library, but it also has no effect.

Comment: `numpy.seterr(all='raise')`

Comment: I tried that, but it has no effect. According to the `seterr` documentation it only handles floating errors (which this isn't)

Comment: @Prune This is not a duplicate. I've seen the linked question, and as far as I can tell it only relates to floating errors (overflows etcs). A ComplexWarning is not such a floating error and is not caught be `seterr`

Comment: Then try the `warning` module in the standard library. You should put what you've tried in your question. Edit your question so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @MichaelGoerz: Thanks; I see the difference.  Reopened.  My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [stdlib warnings filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) causes these to raise instead of print:

```
>>> warnings.filterwarnings(action="error", category=np.ComplexWarning)
>>> b = np.array(a, dtype=np.float64)
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

You can reset it to default filters with [`warnings.resetwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.resetwarnings).